# How to get rid of trailing comma in loop?

Tags: loops

How would I get rid of the trailing comma in this loop?

```
    outStream.print(" float on lines: ");
    for(int j = 0; j < intLines.length; j++){      
        totalFloats = totalFloats + floatLines[j];

        if(floatLines[j] > 0){
            outStream.printf("%d, ", floatLines[j]);
        }
    }
    if(totalFloats == 0){
        outStream.print("none");
    }
    outStream.println();
```

Comment: Have you accidentally placed a ',' after `%d`?

Comment: No, I need it to print a list with commas in it, but once it gets to the last number, I don't want it to print a comma (ex "float on lines: 16, 20, 32," but I need it to print "float on lines: 16, 20, 32").

Answer (score 1):

Just add a check for the final loop, if it's the final loop just use `outStream.printf("%d ", floatLines[j]);`

Example:

```
outStream.print(" float on lines: ");
string separator = "%d";
for(int j = 0; j < intLines.length; j++){      
    totalFloats = totalFloats + floatLines[j];

    if (j != 0 && floatLines[j] > 0)
    {
       separator = ", %d";
    }    
    if(floatLines[j] > 0){
         outStream.printf(separator, floatLines[j]);
    } 

}
if(totalFloats == 0){
    outStream.print("none");
}
outStream.println();
```

Comment: That sort of worked, but instead it printed, "float on lines: 16, 20, 32, 0".  What would I do to get rid of that 0?

Comment: What are the values inside the floatLines[] array?

Comment: integer numbers, the program reads an input file and finds what lines a declared variable is on (ex int variableName = 0;)... Then it finds what line it is on and puts it into the array with the corresponding index.

Comment: Now it printed "float on lines: 16, 20, 32,"

Comment: Now it prints "float on lines: 162032".  Lol I've had a lot of trouble with this

Comment: Sorry that was my fault, I had the if and else around the wrong way. My last edit should work

Comment: It prints "float on lines: 16, 20, 32," again lol. And by the way the array has a max value of 1001 (indexes 0 - 1000).

Comment: Ok, I see the issue. I'll refactor it for you in an hour

Comment: Uh, the only issue is the fact that I don't know how to user separators.... This is a project for school lol.  Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Oh no that's just a variable. The `"%d"` is a string, because we need it to change I just stored it in a variable called `separator`, you can change the name of the variable to anything you like :)

Comment: Never mind, I changed my code around completely and finally got it to work :P  Simplifying my code made a huge difference!  Thanks again for your willingness to help!